# Python combine lines without blank new lines

Tags: python, newline

i need your help with the following problem. I have some large textfiles for example:

> ```
> This is the Name of the Person
>
> This is his surname
>
> He likes to sing 
> every time.
> ```

I only want to merge the line `He likes to sing` with `every time.` because i do other regex stuff with each string after this.

So the output should be:

> ```
> This is the Name of the Person
>
> This is his surname
>
> He likes to sing every time.
> ```

So ive tried it with:

```
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
              if not line.startswith('\n'):
                line.replace('\n', '')
                print(line)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `print()` will add a newline at the end of a line by default. Try `print(line, end="")`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
        lines = [i.replace('\n', ' ') for i in f_in.read().split('\n\n')]

    # here you do something with your `lines`
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better to do it like this:

```
for file_name in file_list:
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="UTF-8", errors="ignore") as file:
        text = file.read()
        text_blocks = text.split("\n\n")
        for text_block in text_blocks:
            formatted_text_block = text_block.replace("\n", "")
            # then you can do what ever you want with this new block of text
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the sections on `\n\n`, then join up each section by splitting on `\n`:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.read().split("\n\n"):
        print("".join(line.split("\n")) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
This is the Name of the Person

This is his surname

He likes to sing every time.
```

If you want to write the output back to a new file, you can do this:

```
with open("data.txt") as f, open("output.txt", mode="w") as o:
    for line in f.read().split("\n\n"):
        o.write("".join(line.split("\n")) + "\n\n")
```

We need to add an extra `\n` because we're not not printing.

**output.txt**

```
This is the Name of the Person

This is his surname

He likes to sing every time.
```

Another option is to collect all the lines into a single string, then write the whole string contents to the file:

```
with open("data.txt") as f, open("output.txt", mode="w") as o:
    lines = "\n\n".join("".join(line.split("\n")) for line in f.read().split("\n\n"))
    o.writelines(lines)
```

The issue with the above solutions is that they read the whole file contents into memory with `read()` before processing, which could be slow for large files.

Instead we could make a generator function which yields the sections from the file:

```
def collect_file_sections(f):
    section = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            section.append(line)
            continue
        yield section
        section = []
    yield section
```

Then write the sections like this:

```
with open("data.txt") as f, open("output.txt", mode="w") as o:
    o.writelines("\n\n".join(" ".join(section) for section in collect_file_sections(f)))
```